# HTML returns: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: html, .htaccess, server, hosting

I am currently working on a beta website (CentOs -> Plesk) and using Atom as my editor.

From the set-up till now I always recieve the following error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when changing something in my html, css, javascript. Which just breaks my website.

I came here in hope that someone had same problem, and maybe can give me a solution for that :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Both errors “No data receive ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE” and “Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)” :
https://www.wiknix.com/solved-err_empty_response-no-data-received/

Read The following article and comments below .. Maybe This link will solved your ERROR 
Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error but it was browser issue for me. It wasn’t anything wrong with my site or hosting provider or theme error. I just open a command prompt and enter few commands to solve this error.
You can check command lists from below reference:
https://wildtricks.com/err_empty_response-google-chrome-windows/